# Removing the default <a href> action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to stop the page from loading the next page when someone clicks on a `<a>`
tag instead i want it to give the href value so for example "www.google.com" and then do a jquery `.load()`
which is like this

```
$(".window").load(hrefvalue);
```

i know i could just change all the href values to fire up a javascript function but that takes a bit of time so im just looking for the easiest way.

so i want it to do

1. stop the page loading the next part on a **`<a href`** click.
2. get the href value e.g http://www.google.com.
3. and then do a jquery `(.load()` or `$.ajax()`) call for the href page.

Comment: take a look at preventDefault: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: You can't `$.load` from a different domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();    // Now the link doesn't do anything
  var href = this.href;      // The link's URL is in this variable
});
```

Comment: this wont work for newly created a tags from javascript functions

Comment: You can't steal common knowledge ;)

Answer (score 1):

could do something like

```
$(document).on('click', '*[href]', function(e) {
   // Whatever you're trying to do
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Are there any other tags that you can click on aside from `<a>` tags?

Comment: @Blender I believe there was some talk of "any tag as a link" for HTML6, but I can't seem to find it now...

Comment: you can click on any tag, this would allow you to have href on a span, or a button (although it wouldnt do anything, and isnt valid html, it would allow for it)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','a[href]',function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax(href,function(data){
        $(your_container).html(data);
        //data is the HTML returned
        //note that ajax is bound to the
        //same origin policy
        //any request outside your domain won't work
    })

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">...</a>
```

And after then you can write your script for this anchor.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  $.ajax({
     url: href,
     success: function(data) {
      alert('Load was performed.');
    }
  });
});
```